# Nginx - How to I add Cache-Control to sitemap.xml so its never cached?

Tags: nginx

How do I set up Nginx to never cache sitemaps?

this was my idea:

```
location ~* \.(xml)$ {
  expires -1;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats correct if you have a add_header directive at previous levels. If not then

location ~* .(xml)$ {

add_header Expires -1;

log_not_found off;
}

A negative time sets the cache-control header to no-cache.

A better way to play with headers is to use nginx v1.4.3 that has the module more_set_headers and more_clear_headers in order to replace or set the headers from origin.
You can download the module from [here](https://github.com/agentzh/headers-more-nginx-module/archive/v0.23.tar.gz).
More information [HERE](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule)